# Is there a name for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

Consider n buckets that contain from 0 to x items. From time to time something is added (moved, removed) to (between, from) any bucket(s).

Once in a while runs something that will have to calculate what items have to be moved from their bucket to another with minimal amount of moves so number of items in each bucket will be almost equal.

Is there a name for this algorithm?

Comment: This is similar to *load balancing*.